# Knockout add my own data-bind attribute like With

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Sorry for my bad title, but I am not really sure what to call this and properly someone can guide me in the correct direction.

I am working in Typescript and class KnockoutFileDropArea.

What I then would like to do is something like the following:

```
<div data-bind="with:fileDropArea">
    <div data-bind="foreach:files">
    </div>
</div>
```

The KnockoutFileDropArea has the property files ect.

Above is straight forward. Just adding a property on my viewmodel of KnockoutFileDropArea ect. But what I need to do is when it binds my KnockoutFileDropArea i want to do something with the HtmlElement that it was bound for.

What can I do to attach something to the element when my KnockoutFileDropArea is bound?

Would it be better to create a new (cant remember what they are called, 'BindingHandler'), like with. So it was something like `<div data-bind="droparea: fileDropArea">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good choice would be to create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Your custom binding could either just perform the functionality that you want on the element and run when the element is bound and you could use it with the `with` binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        //do something with the element
    }
}
```

Otherwise, your custom binding could wrap the `with` binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        //do something with the element

        return ko.bindingHandlers["with"].init.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {

        return ko.bindingHandlers["with"].update.apply(this, arguments);
   }
};
```

**Update:** In KO 3.1, the `with` binding no longer has an `update` function, as it can now use a computed in the `init` for that purpose. So, the `update` function above could be removed.

Note: the `with` is quoted, as older IE does not like using `with` as a property name.

Comment: Thank you. One comment. Lets say i do <div data-bind="test:helloworld"> with this binding. Could i from the init method set a value on the viewmodel. Viewmodel.hellowrod = new MyDropClass();

Comment: The fourth argument (`data` in my example) is your viewmodel or it can be accessed from the 5th argument as `context.$data` (better for KO 3.0, if you want to support observable view models). Generally bindings aren't creating properties on the view model, but there are definitely scenarios where it can be useful.

Comment: I created the property fileHandler : KnockoutFileHander = ko.observable() and plan to set that in the init function. Was just wondering if there was a reason for me having to set it on the viewmodel, if the binding could do it when used.